# stripping text from passed argument to windows bat command

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

on windows I have created `ydl.bat` file that accepts url.

`youtube-dl.exe -f 140 %1`

what I want to do is to strip everything from `?` onwards if url passed is like this `https://youtu.be/1j6muwUGXw?list=RDK2_g8u0bUc`

I can do in python but I believe its fewer steps if we do it in windows pragmatically

Comment: I have created a ydl.bat file. I am beginner in windows.

Comment: No, what have you done to try stripping the data? There are ample guides online for processing strings in Batch. Have you done research? Have you tried doing this yourself? We are not a script writing service. Once you've tried something and come up against something you cannot figure out, then we can help you get past that difficult point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea on how it could be done:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set url=%1
if "%url%"=="" set url=https://youtu.be/1j6muwUGXw?list=RDK2_g8u0bUc
echo Old Url: %url%
echo.

:GetLength
set /a Lenght+=1
if /i not "!url:~0,-%Lenght%!"=="" goto :GetLength

for /l %%a in (0,1,%Lenght%) do (
if /i "!url:~%%a,1!"=="?" set url=!url:~0,%%a! & goto :next
)
:next
echo New Url: %url%
echo.
pause
Exit
```

Comment: too late, I ended up writing the tool in python

Answer (score 0):

Use **`?`** as delimiter and use only the characters of the 1st token:

```py
for /f delims^=?  %%i in ("%~1")do youtube-dl.exe -f 140 %%i
```

An alternative to shortened links:
**[How to obtain the real URL behind a shortened URL using `cURL`](https://tecnoysoft.com/en/how-to-obtain-the-real-url-behind-a-shortened-url-using-curl/)**

```py
@echo off 

for /f tokens^=2 %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%curl.exe -sLI "%~1"^|find "Location:"
')do for /f tokens^=1delims^=^& %%Y in ('echo\"%%~i"')do youtube-dl.exe -f 140 %%Y
```

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[For /f Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

Comment: will this work on windows ?

Comment: @ChangZhao yes, on/for Windows